# Python async function not working when called outside run loop

Tags: python, async-await

I am writing an abstraction layer over a [request-response](https://github.com/afflux/pysomeip/blob/master/tools/get.py) library example. In the original example the request packet is sent to server inside an infinite loop which I have generalized here.

```py
from their_stack import create_endpoint

async def run(remote_ip, remote_port):
    server_connection = await create_endpoint(remote_ip, remote_port)

   while True:
        server_connection.stack_send_request() #a callback in server_connection will be called when response received
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        server_connnection.close()

def main():
    asyncio.run(
        run("127.0.0.1", 9999)
    )
```

I want to be able to send requests ad-hoc rather than in a loop . So I separated the send functionality as a separate function.

```py
from their_stack import create_endpoint

async def my_send_request(remote_ip, remote_port):
    server_connection = await create_endpoint(remote_ip, remote_port)
    server_connection.stack_send_request()
    server_connnection.close()


def main():
    asyncio.run(my_send_request("127.0.0.1", 9999))
```

But when I run it I'm not getting the responses from the server. From the server logs I know the requests are being received by the service.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API works if I borrow the sleep from the original loop. A 0.1 second sleep works fine. So the final send function looks like this.

```py
async def my_send_request(remote_ip, remote_port):
    server_connection = await create_endpoint(remote_ip, remote_port)
    server_connection.stack_send_request()
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    server_connection.close()
```